# How to call table valued function from linked server in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, linked-server

I want  to call a table valued function from `Server02` in `Server01`; `Server01` and `Server02` are linked servers.

The RPC and RPC Out options is true;

I write this query

```
SELECT *
FROM [Server02].[db].[dbo].[CalcAzarTrnForSevenSinFestival](19540675)
```

`CalcAzarTrnForSevenSinFestival` is a table valued function in `Server02`

I get this error

> Msg 4122, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Remote table-valued function calls are not allowed.

I searched about this problem some people say add `NOLOCK` option to your query

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Server02].[db].[dbo].[CalcAzarTrnForSevenSinFestival](19540675) (NOLOCK)
```

and I this error

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 15, Line 9
>   'Server02.db.dbo.CalcAzarTrnForSevenSinFestival' is not a recognized function name.

Generally can I call table valued function on linked server in SQL Server?

Comment: As per Msg 4122 you cannot directly call UDFs over linked server connections. If the connection is configured to allow stored procedure calls (RPC OUT) you could probably do something awful like `exec Server02.db.dbo.sp_executesql N'select * from dbo.CalcAzarTrnForSevenSinFestival(19540675)'` though.

Comment: See [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Answer (score 0):

Removing (NOLOCK) from linked server queries worked for me (SSMS v18.9.1). These were linked server calls inside of functions to give you the context.